# Placeholder on a @Html.Dropdownlist that is not selectable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

How do i put a placeholder on my @Html.Dropdownlist that is not selectable.
I implemented chosen-jquery on my dropdown.
My code is as per below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", new SelectList(new Ahib.Membership.UserFacade().GetAllUsers(), "Id", "Username"), "-select a system owner-", new { @class="chosen1-select" })
```

Currently my dropdownlist has a placeholder but the "-select a system owner-" becomes a selectable value which i dont want. How do solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your list to the selectitem list and apply your disabled attribute from the controller itself.

like this

assuming your model is like this

```
class user
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
```

Convert your list to `List<SelectListItem>` like this, note here I am disabling the select a system owner entry.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<user> users = new List<user>();
            users.Add(new user { Id = 1, Username = "test1" });
            users.Add(new user { Id = 2, Username = "test2" });

            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-select a system owner-", Value = "0", Disabled = true });
            foreach (var item in users)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = item.Username,
                    Value = item.Id.ToString()
                });
            }

            ViewBag.listItems = list;
            return View();
        }
```

and in view use it like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("test", ViewBag.listItems as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested. The "-select a system owner-" appear but not as a placeholder. It appeared as an option that is not selectable. When i open the form, the default value for the dropdownlist is still "test1" instead of "-select a system owner-" as a placeholder.

Comment: @matrixmy002 change your select a system owner to `list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-select a system owner-", Value = "0", Disabled = true ,Selected = true});`

Comment: I tried your suggested solution. It worked for a normal dropdownlist but since i'm using chosen jquery, if i type/search "select", the option "select a system owner" appear as the search result whereas it should be "no result match".

Comment: @matrixmy002 that is totally a different solution then you provided but still you can do this with slight change of jquery, try to explore https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ and you will get the result you want.,